# Show Hide DIV on Image mouseover using Jquery Issues

Tags: jquery, html

**Background:** I have the Picture below wrapped under the DIV tag. When user does the `mouseover` on the Image the `overlayInfo` DIV tag appears (code below).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#overlayInfo").hide();

            $("#ProjectPicture").hover(function(event) {
                $("#overlayInfo").show();
            });

            $("#ProjectPicture").mouseleave( 'mouseleave', function() {
                $("#overlayInfo").hide();
            });

        }); 
    </script>

<div id="ProjectPicture">
  <img src="image1.png">
</div>

<div id="overlayInfo">
     <i class="fa fa-cloud" title="Web"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" title="Shopping Cart"></i>
</div>
```

**Issue:** There are multiple issues that I am seeing on mouseover event of the image. The image size is 250 x 200 pixels.

1. The `overlayInfo` tag appears intermittently on image mouseover
2. The `overlayInfo` tag flickers when user moves the mouse on the image instead of being
   stable

Is there anything that I am doing wrong.

Added JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2My79/5/

Comment: Hi, I think you're using the wrong events.. I reckon using $.hover would be better. can you do a JSFiddle and I can convert it for you? Thanks

Comment: @JFit I tried with the hover as well but it is still the same

Comment: please add a JSFiddle so others can see what makes your issue happen

Comment: @YashmanGupta you must make a fiddle... Add some code in here... http://jsfiddle.net/2My79/

Comment: @Bhavik I have made the changes see http://jsfiddle.net/2My79/

Comment: @YashmanGupta after making the changes you need to update the fiddle and share the new fiddle link in your question

Comment: I am not sure why this question has been down voted. care to explain

Comment: @Bhavik sorry, using Fiddle first time. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/2My79/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Update:** The issue is closed as I have found the solution that eliminates the original issue as well as the workaround that I took
>   yesterday by adding `pointer-events: none`. Now I no longer need to
>   use it.
>
> The solution that worked for me can be found @
>   http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/

@Bhavik thanks for the Fiddle help.

To make the flickering effect go-away on mouseover of `#ProjectPicture` I have added `pointer-events: none;` in the CSS of `#overlayInfo`. The only downside of this is that it stops showing any tooltip that I have in the div tag.

The complete source is @ http://jsfiddle.net/yashmangupta/5zBNE/1/. 
Since I have to close this issue ASAP, therefore I am going ahead with my solution but am still looking for experts recommendations

```
#overlayInfo
{
   position: absolute;
   width: 97%;
   top: 10px;
   height: 183px;
   bottom:  0%;
   border: 0px solid;
   z-index: 99999;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="ProjectPicture">
   <img src="image1.png">
</div>

<div id="overlayInfo">
   <i class="fa fa-cloud" title="Web"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" title="Shopping Cart"></i>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#overlayInfo").hide();

        $("#ProjectPicture").mouseover(function() {
            $("#overlayInfo").show();
        });

        $("#ProjectPicture").mouseleave(function() {
            $("#overlayInfo").hide();
        });

    });
```

And a random CSS for overlayInfo div:

```
#overlayInfo { display: none; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: #000; }
```

Comment: Sorry I provided wrong fiddle :P I just edited it take a look http://jsfiddle.net/K6day/

Comment: Are you testing in multiple environments? its not working properly in chrome man

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your element is already visible. Try something like this:

```
$("#ProjectPicture").on( 'mouseenter', function() {
    $target = $("#overlayInfo");
    if( $target.is(':visible') ) return;
    $target.show();
}).on( 'mouseleave', function() {
    $target = $("#overlayInfo");
    if( !$target.is(':visible') ) return;
    $target.hide();
});
```

Comment: What do yo mean? No matters if the element has already visible or not. With that check you just prevent to show something that is already shown. Same with hiding. So you can prevent those Intermittents too. I tested it on jsfiddle and works.

Comment: when the page loads the element is hidden, and when the mouse is over on the image, the DIV tag is shown. The issue is that it is flickering. You can check the fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/2My79/1/

Comment: Uhm, I don't appreciate flickering. Checked in Chrome and Firefox latest versions: http://jsfiddle.net/2My79/3/

Comment: checked in IE11, Chrome and FF all latest browsers. Still the same issue. Unless I add `pointer-events: none;` in the `overlayInfo` CSS but that stops all the events such as Tooltip of `overlayInfo` DIV Tag

Comment: The matter is that I can't see any problem. The fiddle example is working as I think is expected. I mean, I don't see any flickerings or weird effects :/

Comment: you need to move the mouse over on image

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, I move the mouse along the image and the overlay divs are not flickering... check it: http://tinyurl.com/k2buft7 (it's a video mp4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55565/discussion-between-yashman-gupta-and-kmsdev).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well:

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
        { 
          $("#ProjectPicture").mouseover(function() {
         // do work for mouse over
                $("#overlayInfo").show();
        }).mouseleave(function() {
         $("#overlayInfo").hide();
         // do work for mouse out
           });
        });
```

and Your html :

```
<div id="ProjectPicture">
  <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-NnUDSkolO6M/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAPg/Rp2eTavq49w/s120-c/photo.jpg">
</div>

<div id="overlayInfo" style=""mouseoverlay:none>
  hello
     <li class="fa fa-cloud" title="Web"></li>
     <li class="fa fa-shopping-cart" title="Shopping Cart"></li>
</div>
```

live example :  http://jsbin.com/tocotita/2/edit

Comment: thanks, you can check the fiddle that explains http://jsfiddle.net/2My79/1/ the issue.